# TS2339: Property 'SOLDE' does not exist on type 'AdvTitres'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array and I just want to retrieve the value of the `SOLDE` variable.

The JSON file is available [here](http://jsonblob.com/966692805254856704).

The error message is the following:

```
error TS2339: Property 'SOLDE' does not exist on type 'AdvTitres'.
<td> {{details.SOLDE}}</td>
```

**internal-transfert-watch.response.ts**

```
export interface InternalTransfertWatchResponse extends ApiResponse {
    TRANS: AdvTitres;
}

export interface AdvTitres {

    TRANS: {
        TITRE: {
            LABEL: string,
            ISIN: string,
            SVM: number,
        },
        SOLDE: number,
        QTE_VENTE: number,
        QTE_BLOQ: number,
        QTE_TRF: number,

    }[];
}
```

**internal-transfert-watch.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class InternalTransfertWatchService {
  private readonly api: string = environment.api;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private store: Store) {}

    getTransfert(svm: string): Observable<InternalTransfertWatchResponse> {
      return this.http.post<InternalTransfertWatchResponse>(this.api + `/NEKKYN`, {
        SVM: parseInt(svm)
     
      }, { headers: { AddCustomer: '' } });
    }
    
}
```

**internal-transfert-watch.component.ts**

```
export class InternalTransfertWatchComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

  details?: AdvTitres;
  svm: string | null = null;

  constructor(   
    private service: InternalTransfertWatchService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.svm = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('svm');
  
    if (!this.svm) {
      this.goBack();
      return;
    }
    this.getDetails();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }

  private getDetails(): void {
    this.service.getTransfert(this.svm!).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(res => {
      if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
        this.details = res.TRANS;
      

      }
    });
  }


  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }


}
```

**internal-transfert-watch.component.html**

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="details">
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped spaceLeft">
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <th>Solde</th>
                <td> {{details.SOLDE}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I probably missed a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export interface InternalTransfertWatchResponse extends ApiResponse {
  TRANS: AdvTitres[];
}

export interface AdvTitres {

    TITRE: {
        LABEL: string,
        ISIN: string,
        SVM: number,
    },
    SOLDE: number,
    QTE_VENTE: number,
    QTE_BLOQ: number,
    QTE_TRF: number,

}
```

Comment: Thanks, in the `private getDetails() method: void {
     this.service.getTransfer(this.svm!).pipe(
       takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
     ).subscribe(res => {
       if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
         this. details = res. TRANS;
       }
     });
   }
`
, I have an error message `Type 'AdvTitres[]' is missing the following properties from type 'AdvTitres': TITLE, SOLDE, QTE_VENTE, QTE_BLOQ, QTE_TRF`, what should I modify on `this.details = res. TRANS;` ? Thanks to you

Comment: Could you send the response you are getting there ? From the looks of it the response is not the same type as AdvTitres interface

Comment: It works in the component, I added `details?: AdvTitres[] = [];`. However, in the HTML, I have this: `<td> {{details.TRANS.SOLDE }}</td>`, the error message is still the same. `error TS2339: Property 'TRANS' does not exist on type 'AdvTitres[]'.`, thank you a lot

Comment: TRANS is an array, so if you want to access it on the view  it has to be inside a for loop or by indexing the element with a number, such as details.TRANS[0].SOLDE

Comment: I tried with ` <td>{{details[0].SOLDE}}</td>`, it works ! Thank you a lot for your help and your time.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to notice that indeed, `SOLDE` is not part of your interface. It's part of the `TRANS` subobject, so you need to use

```
myObj.TRANS.SOLDE
```

Comment: I tried however I got an error message too: `error TS2339: Property 'SOLDE' does not exist on type '{ TITLE: { LABEL: string; ISIN: string; SVM: number; }; SOLDE: number; QTY_SALE: number; QTE_BLOQ: number; QTE_TRF: number; }[]'.`

Comment: Try and get rid of the TRANS prop on AdvTitres interface. The way you have it you would need to query obj.TRANS.TRANS.SOLDE

Comment: @WebDever, I tried, but I still have the same problem. :S